# Properties of orthonormal basis in $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: linear-algebra

Is the intuition that at least one of the vectors of any $\mathbb{R}^n$ orthonormal basis has all entries $e_i\geq 0$ or $e_i\leq 0$ correct?

Comment: The case $n=2$ being obvious, You can start with proving or disproving it for $n=3$.

Comment: Intuition: grouping vectors in $\Bbb R^n$ by the signs of their coordinates results in $2^n$ orthants. The two special types of vectors you describe comprise only $2$ of those $2^n$ orthants. Surely there must be room to fit $n$ orthogonal vectors in the remaining $2^n-2$ orthants!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $n = 3$, consider $e_1 = \begin{bmatrix}-1/3 \\ 2/3 \\ 2/3 \end{bmatrix}$, $e_2 = \begin{bmatrix}2/3 \\ -1/3 \\ 2/3 \end{bmatrix}$, and $e_3 = \begin{bmatrix}2/3 \\ 2/3 \\ -1/3 \end{bmatrix}$.

For larger $n$, try to find vectors $\{e_k\}_{k = 1}^{n}$ of the form $(e_k)_j = \begin{cases}a & \text{if} \ j \neq k \\ b & \text{if} \ j = k\end{cases}$ where $a$ and $b$ are constants with opposite signs (which could depend on $n$).

Comment: Additional intuition: the standard basis for $\Bbb R^3$ doesn't fail the condition in the OP, but it just barely doesn't fail it. Rotating that standard basis around the axis determined by $(1,1,1)$ should create a counterexample to the OP's question. And indeed, this example is the rotation of the standard basis around that axis by $\pi$ (in other words, its reflection in the line $(t,t,t)$). All the other nontrivial rotations, I believe, also yield counterexamples to the OP's question; and I suspect the same phenomenon happens in higher dimensions.

Comment: Is it generalisable for any orthonormal basis in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Yes, if you try to find an orthonormal basis in the form I listed, the two conditions are $\|e_k\|_2 = 1$ and $\left\langle e_k,e_{\ell}\right\rangle = 0$, both of which give you equations for $a$ and $b$ in terms of $n$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.